# Creating a new row when there is more than one column

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

How would you force create a new row in Excel wherever there is a an additional column (i.e. more than one) - as seen below?

I'm currently doing this manually and it is quite time consuming.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently had to do this exact thing, and came up with two solutions:

1) Export as CSV, run several search+replaces on the data with a text tool, re-import into Excel, then use a formula to create the duplicate user numbers for empty first rows.

2) Write 15 lines of PHP code to turn the CSV into a new CSV.

The second is MUCH more effective and flexible, but it requires a basic coding environment.